# PHP-Login.net (Login MVC): Render

Tags: php

I use the MVC Script from php-login.net (Advanced Version https://github.com/panique/php-login).

The pages are rendered there in the controller (like dashboard.php):

```
function index()
{
    $this->view->render('dashboard/index');
}
```

Now I have to render a lot of reports in this section (all php-files)
Problem is I need now for every file the line in the controller

```
function umsatz_dynamics(){$this->view->render('dashboard/umsatz_dynamics'); }
.....
```

I want to do this automatically by s.th. like this:

```
function __call($name, $arguments) {
    var_dump($arguments);
    echo $arguments;

        $arguments = $this->tuWasDamit($arguments);

        if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/../views/'.$name.'/'.$arguments.'.php')){
            $this->view->render($name.'/'.$arguments);
        }
}

private function tuWasDamit($arguments) {
    // $arguments verarbeiten
    return $arguments;
}
```

But the __call-function isnt called. Maybe it´s blocked by another function. But I dont cant find anything.

What to do?

Comment: When naming methods - don't name them in german. They should be always named in english regarding developer's native language.

Comment: @djay That's up to the developing team. If German is the standard language everybody in the team understands, there's little chance an English speaker will ever have to work with the code and it makes it much easier for the team to work with German method names, especially if they contain specialised business jargon, that's a perfectly fine decision to make.